# Calling methods in doPost() without slowing down Results Page

Tags: java, servlets

The following index.html calls the (below) servet’s doPost to see if a url is available on auction. Everything runs great. However, I am looking to execute two additional methods from other classes *after the page redirect*. My problem is the other two additional methods take a long time to finish so I can’t put them directly after the response.sendRedirect as they hold up the initial response.

How can I send the redirect immediately (exactly as below)while then calling the other two methods which need the same String data variable found in doPost to operate?

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>URL Auction Search Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<CENTER>
 <FORM ACTION="/ResultServlet/Results" METHOD=GET>
   <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="st">
   <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE=Submit>
  </FORM>
</CENTER>
</body>
</html>
```

**Servlet**

```
@WebServlet("/Results")
public class Results extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       public static String str="";

    private String businessLogic(String q){
        try {
            str = new compute.URL.GetAvailURI( "https://www.registerdomains.com/auctionAPI/Key:a05u3***1F2r6Z&urlSearch="+q);
            /*more boring number crunching */
            return str;
            }
/*
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    }
*/
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Results r = new Results();
        String st = request.getParameter("st");
    String data = r.businessLogic(st);
        response.sendRedirect("results/resultActionURL.html?st="+data);
//IDEALLY I WOULD LIKE TO CALL outsideMethod1(data) and outsideMethodTWO(data) HERE 
    //BUT IT TAKES TOO LONG. HOW CAN I RUN THEM W/O SLOWING DOWN THE RESPONSE 
             //(LIKE A ProcessBuilder call to a shell for example where there's almost a handoff)
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the client need the results of outsideMethod1 and outsideMethod2, or do you just need them to execute following the doPost operation?

Comment: The other 2 methods produce two other results pages- but I can work on those while the client gets the initial results page. They dont have to be part of the doPost, but I need the String data that I create in doPost()

Comment: Why wouldn't you do 3 calls from the client?  The initial call would return the data and redirect to another page.  That page would perform 2 calls with the returned data to run the other 2 operations?

Comment: I thought about that too, but since the hand off of data may be a bit large (String data), I would prefer to do it on the server side. Also, I may be way off, but I prefer to do the calls on my server side as everything stays local here and I don't have to worry about different browsers and client's bandwidth (external variables that I can't control).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute those methods in a separate thread.

```
public class Results extends HttpServlet{
...
  private Thread t;
  private volatile String myResult;
...
  protected void doPost(...){
  ...
      t = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
          myResult = outsideMethod1(data);
        }
      }
      t.start();
  }
}
```

Then in the method where you want to get the result back:

```
t.join();
String result = myResult;
...
```

and similarly for outsideMethodTWO

Comment: This would be a incorrect approach if you ever had overlapping calls from multiple clients.

Comment: I'm sorry. James is right.  You should keep a synchronized HashMap which maps clients to results.